# @item.BodyText in not raw format in MVC3

Tags: .net, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

When I am using @item.BodyText I am getting the raw html output - with html tags that are in it as strings. It looks like that:

```
<p>State of Louisiana for state funded&nbsp; dispensing program<br>June 21, 2011<br><br>Software update:<br>Version 3.1 is 10% faster<br>
```

And I need those html tags not to be presented as strings but to work and format text. So that it would look more like that:

> State of Louisiana for state funded dispensing
>   program June 21, 2011
>
> Software update: Version 3.1 is 10% faster

I am using Umbraco 5 based on .Net Framework 4 and MVC3.

Code of my partial view:

```
@inherits RenderViewPage
@using Umbraco.Cms.Web;
@{
    var Homepage = @DynamicModel;
    while (Homepage.ContentType.Alias != "homePage")
    {
        Homepage = Homepage.Parent;
    }
}

    @foreach (var item in Homepage.Children)
    {
        if (@item.CurrentTemplate != null)
        {
            var childName = item.Name ?? "(No name yet)";
            if (childName == "News")
            {              
                @item.BodyText           
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried using `@Umbraco.Field(Model, "bodyText")` instead of `@item.BodyText` but then I got content of current page, and not "News" page that I need.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Razor this happens for security reasons. All view output is Html encoded to prevent injections.

You always need to explicitly state that you don't want Razor to HTML encode your raw output, you can do this by wrapping your statement with the `Html.Raw()`helper method:

Replace:

```
@item.BodyText
```

with:

```
@Html.Raw(item.BodyText)
```

Comment: Of course, you should only output raw HTML when you know it's safe. :-)

Comment: Sure thing. However since it's a cms he is coding against it's kind of what it is supposed todo ;)

Comment: If the CMS allows <p> how do you know it won't allow <script>

Comment: Actually, I would absolutely expect a CMS to allow both, this is what these raw html fields in cms are for. There is no reliable way to filter for malicious html, if you need to be sure nothing is injected you will need to go with a html abstraction language like markdown

Answer (score 1):

In your model you need to specify your property as a different type of string:

```
public string BodyText { get; set; }
public HtmlString BodyHtml
{
    get
    {
        return new HtmlString(BodyText);
    }
}
```

Then you could use:

```
@item.BodyHtml
```

without having to use any HtmlHelper methods in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to replace:

```
@item.BodyText
```

with:

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(item.BodyText)
```

Comment: The recommended way of doing this is to use the `Raw` helper method:  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/announcing-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate-2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good reason that Razor encodes output. You need to protect against XSS. You should wrap the Html.Raw inside an HTML sanitizer. one approach is to use [HtmlAgility Pack](http://HtmlAgility%20Pack) 
See http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/24346
If you can guarantee the DB will never be compromised then you can skip the sanitizer. DB/CMS systems have been comprimised, folks have been tricked, etc.